# How to know Ignite non-heap memory usage?

Tags: java, ignite

I have allocated 5 GB Non heap memory to Ignite as can be verified at application startup.

> ```
> [13:09:56] Topology snapshot [ver=1, servers=1, clients=0, CPUs=4, offheap=4.9GB, heap=2.6GB]
> [13:09:56]   ^-- Node [id=AC62049E-CB7B-4BB6-B19D-56C17B695A8D, clusterState=ACTIVE]
> [13:09:56] Data Regions Configured:
> [13:09:56]   ^-- default [initSize=2.0 GiB, maxSize=3.9 GiB, persistenceEnabled=false]
> [13:09:56]   ^-- Buffer_Region [initSize=512.0 MiB, maxSize=1000.0 MiB, persistenceEnabled=false]
> ```

But during the cluster metrics, I get non heap size as -1%.

> ```
> Metrics for local node (to disable set 'metricsLogFrequency' to 0)
>     ^-- Node [id=ac62049e, name=dm123, uptime=00:07:00.046]
>     ^-- H/N/C [hosts=1, nodes=1, CPUs=4]
>     ^-- CPU [cur=0.33%, avg=2.39%, GC=0%]
>     ^-- PageMemory [pages=158231]
>     ^-- Heap [used=493MB, free=81.32%, comm=960MB]
>     ^-- Non heap [used=112MB, free=-1%, comm=117MB]
>     ^-- Outbound messages queue [size=0]
>     ^-- Public thread pool [active=0, idle=0, qSize=0]
>     ^-- System thread pool [active=0, idle=6, qSize=0]
> ```

What is this Non-Heap size, in this metric? How can I get the real non-heap size in use?

Also I don't know what `comm` means in the metrics; couldn't find it in documentation either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug in Ignite. I found an open ticket for the fix - [IGNITE-5583.](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-5583)

Update: 
The original issue seems to be resolved for 2.7 according to [IGNITE-9305](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-9305)

What version do you use?

Comment: Thanks!. I upgraded to version `2.7.6` where this problem is fixed.